# How to find process name?

Tags: command-line, process

Does every service that is active running have a process that can be seen by `ps` command on linux?

If yes, how can I find the related process name?

For example if `ntp` is running, should I see it by the name `ntp` in `ps -aux | grep ntp`?

Answer (score 1):

> does every service that is active running have a process that can be seen by ps command on linux

Yes.

> for example if ntp is running, should I see it by the name ntp in ps -aux | grep ntp? thanks

Yes.

```
$ ps -aux | grep ntp
ntp       1142  0.0  0.0  40264  1456 ?        Ss   Feb25   5:07 
/usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -c /var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp -u 105:112
```

It will, at least, show the name of the daemon and the user. In the case of "ntp" that would be "ntpd" and "ntp". There are services that (by default) use another user name than the name of the process though: apache user "www-data" as a username and "apache2" is the process.

From comments:

> How can I find the exact process name of a service then?

I tend to know the names of all the processes running on my system. Apache does not work when searching through systemd:

```
$ ps -ef | grep apache
www-data  9799  1638  0 11:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12293  1638  0 12:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 12727  1638  0 12:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 13122  1638  0 12:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 13711  1638  0 12:18 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14004  1638  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14013  1638  0 12:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14120  1638  0 12:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15079  1638  0 12:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15557  1638  0 12:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15783  1638  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15786  1638  0 12:57 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep apache
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep https
$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep http
```

No everything is a systemd service ;)

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. How can I find the exact process name of a service then?

Comment: Run ps followed by grep or use sudo systemctl list-unit-files or sudo service --status-all or even netstat -ano | grep apache

Comment: I thought so too but my test did not show me apache in the services list even though it is installed and running.

Comment: The process name for apache might pe `httpd`

Comment: Nope it was not ;-)

Comment: Apparently it depends. My `systemctl list-unit-files | grep apache2` gives `apache2.service enabled`. I'm running 17.10 and Apache 2.4.27.

Comment: well, thanks again for your help.  In my case, I am looking for PTP process on my system, when I enter /etc/init.d/ptpd status, It shows that ptp is active and running. However, I cannot see its process with ps aux command or pgrep and ... . With systemctl list-unit-files | grep ptp, I will see: ptpd.service  ------------ generated. I don't know any other name for its process.

Comment: Err go :) http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net and you might want to try egrep on occasions, ptp seems to be generating and not running, that means it's helping on the side I guess